# Open RSS links in Webview Activity

Tags: android, parsing, rss, webview, feed

I followed a tutorial on a site to install a RSS Parser in my application. Now, the Reader looks great; however I want to program it so that when a Link is in clicked on, the URL is opened in a webview activity. Is this Possible? I will post the code that makes the RSS feed visible to the reader.

```
public class MessageList extends ListActivity {

private List<Message> messages;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.rss);
    loadFeed();
}
```

;

```
private void loadFeed(){
    try{
        BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
        messages = parser.parse();
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
        for (Message msg : messages){
            titles.add(msg.getTitle());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titles);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Throwable t){
        Log.e("IML News",t.getMessage(),t);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should look at this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html

Then i found you a tutorial:
http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html

Read it and you'll learn how to format your text in textviews like in Html. You'll be able to make clickable links.

Then when a link is clicked just open a webview like usually.

Ask if you want more ;)

Comment: I am not sure how this helps me? I guess I forgot to mention that the RSS links are inside a listview.

Comment: I found the solution, I will post the code for future reference.